# Move ToolTip in WinRT

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

In WinRT (Windows Store Apps), I create a tooltip and set it to an element like this:

```
        dragTip = new ToolTip();
        dragTip.Content = "Test";
        ToolTipService.SetToolTip(element as DependencyObject, dragTip);
        dragTip.IsOpen = true;
```

I want to move this `ToolTip` as the mouse moves. Is there a way to do that? Or another alternative? I want to show a hint to the user as he/she drags an element.

#### Update

Here's the approach I took based on @Sajeetharan's suggestion:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" PointerMoved="homeGrid_PointerMoved" x:Name="homeGrid">
    ....
        <GridView x:Name="content" CanDragItems="True" DragItemsStarting="content_DragItemsStarting">
            ...
        </GridView>
        <Popup Name="DeepZoomToolTip">
            <Border CornerRadius="1" Padding="1"   IsHitTestVisible="False">
                <TextBlock Text="Here is a tool tip" />
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    ....
</Grid>

    private void content_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        DeepZoomToolTip.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void homeGrid_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var position = e.GetCurrentPoint(homeGrid).Position;
        DeepZoomToolTip.HorizontalOffset = position.X;
        DeepZoomToolTip.VerticalOffset = position.Y;
    }
```

Notice that the tooltip will move but not when the item is being dragged.

Comment: What do you mean ? The tooltip following the mouse cursor over the control to which it is attached ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using a popup control , Here is the full Thread [`how to make tooltip move along with mouse`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7cac12c3-8114-459d-bf2c-dc02302b2a1d/how-to-make-tooltip-move-along-with-mouse)

XAML:

```
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
<Image Source="/sam.png" MouseMove="Image_MouseMove" MouseLeave="Image_MouseLeave"/>
<Popup Name="DeepZoomToolTip">
   <Border CornerRadius="1" Padding="1"   IsHitTestVisible="False">
       <TextBlock Text="Here is a tool tip" />
   </Border>
</Popup>
</Canvas>

private void Image_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    DeepZoomToolTip.IsOpen = true;
    DeepZoomToolTip.HorizontalOffset = e.GetPosition(LayoutRoot).X;
    DeepZoomToolTip.VerticalOffset = e.GetPosition(LayoutRoot).Y;
}

private void Image_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    DeepZoomToolTip.IsOpen = false;
}
```

Comment: Well, normally it should work but for some reason when I try this, the `Popup` only moves when the pointer is not pressed (the grid is not in drag mode). I tried adding the events to the main grid but it seems very odd that it's not working.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori can you post the events you had for the tooltip?